# Returning a string minus a specific character between specific characters

Tags: java, string, for-loop, char, charat

I am going through the Java CodeBat exercises. [Here is the one I am stuck on](http://codingbat.com/prob/p180759):

> Look for patterns like "zip" and "zap" in the string -- length-3, starting with 'z' and ending with 'p'. Return a string where for all such words, the middle letter is gone, so "zipXzap" yields "zpXzp".

Here is my code:

```
    public String zipZap(String str){

    String s = ""; //Initialising return string
    String diff = " " + str + " "; //Ensuring no out of bounds exceptions occur

    for (int i = 1; i < diff.length()-1; i++) {
        if (diff.charAt(i-1) != 'z' &&
                diff.charAt(i+1) != 'p') {
            s += diff.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

This is successful for a few of them but not for others. It seems like the `&&` operator is acting like a `||` for some of the example strings; that is to say, many of the characters I want to keep are not being kept. I'm not sure how I would go about fixing it.

A nudge in the right direction if you please! I just need a hint!

Comment: This problem is too vague to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is the other way around. You should do:

```
if (diff.charAt(i-1) != 'z' || diff.charAt(i+1) != 'p') {
    s += diff.charAt(i);
}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
if (!(diff.charAt(i-1) == 'z' && diff.charAt(i+1) == 'p')) {
    s += diff.charAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the perfect use of a regular expression.

The regex `"z.p"` will match any three letter token starting with a z, having any character in the middle, and ending in p. If you require it to be a letter you could use `"z[a-zA-Z]p"` instead.

So you end up with

```
public String zipZap(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("z[a-zA-Z]p", "zp");
}
```

This passes all the tests, by the way.

You could make the argument that this question is about raw string manipulation, but I would argue that that makes this an even better lesson: applying regexes appropriately is a massively useful skill to have!

Comment: Is it better that I become knowledgable about regex before 'mastering' raw string manipulation? Do you use regex frequently?

Comment: I use regular expressions far more often than raw string manipulation. In fact, I almost never use raw string manipulation unless I'm writing the gritty, gritty details inside the guts of a library, or I'm working on a section of code in a very tight loop, neither of which are very common occurrences.

Comment: I see. I guess I should be able to do both fluently; I don't want to be in a position where I've mastered one and have seriously lacking knowledge of the other.

Comment: The difference is that raw string manipulation is mostly common sense and  a little math. Regex is... well... potentially life saving https://xkcd.com/208/ :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public String zipZap(String str) {
    //If bigger than 3, because obviously without 3 variables we just return the string.
    if (str.length() >= 3)
    {
      //Create a variable to return at the end.
      String ret = "";
      //This is a cheat I worked on to get the ending to work easier.
      //I noticed that it wouldn't add at the end, so I fixed it using this cheat.
      int minusAmt = 2;
      //The minus amount starts with 2, but can be changed to 0 when there is no instance of z-p.
      for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - minusAmt; i++)
      {
        //I thought this was a genius solution, so I suprised myself.
        if (str.charAt(i) == 'z' && str.charAt(i+2) == 'p')
        {
          //Add "zp" to the return string
          ret = ret + "zp";
          //As long as z-p occurs, we keep the minus amount at 2.
          minusAmt = 2;
          //Increment to skip over z-p.
          i += 2;
        }
        //If it isn't z-p, we do this.
        else
        {
          //Add the character
          ret = ret + str.charAt(i);
          //Make the minus amount 0, so that we can get the rest of the chars.
          minusAmt = 0;
        }
      }
      //return the string.
      return ret;
    }
    //If it was less than 3 chars, we return the string.
    else
    {
      return str;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you think about this loop?